# Delete with modal confirm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I need delete row with modal confirm. If i delete first row - delete success, but if delete second and later rows, when showWrating(errMessage) because remembered first name parameter. How I can update(set to zero) name parameter every OK button click?

My Index.cshtml:

```
function delRow() {
    vm.onEditRow(
            function (name) {
                    showQuestion(function (isYes) {
                        if (isYes)
                            vm.onDelRow('@Url.Action("DelScheduler")', name,
                                function () {
                                    refreshGrid();
                                },
                                function (errMessage) {
                                    showWrating(errMessage);
                                }
                            );
                    });
                },
                function () {
                    showWrating('@Resources.NotSelectedRow');
                });
        }

    My TypeScript:    

onEditRow(onSuccess: (name: string) => {}, onError: () => {}) 
    {
        if (this.selectScheduler() == null)
                    onError();
                else {
                    onSuccess(this.selectScheduler().name);
                }
        }

onDelRow(url: string, name: string, onSuccess: () => {}, onError: (message: string) => {})
    {   
         this.invokeAjax(url, { name: name }, (data) => {
                            if (!data.succeeded) {
                                onError(data.error);
                            } else {
                                onSuccess();
                        }
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing `name` someplace outside the functions you have provided. One possible place where you are storing it is in `this.selectScheduler().name` Use `name` instead.

Comment: @user2382193 no worries. If it fixed it would appreciate it being marked as the answer.